# Test if flock file locking is supported on a filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, nfs, systems-programming, flock

If one attempts to `flock()` a file on a lockless NFS mount, then `flock` will hang even if `LOCK_NB` is passed.

Is it possible to detect that the filesystem does not support locking ahead of time? Perhaps with something returned from `statfs`?

If not, is there some suitable heuristic for when to avoid file locking? For example, by inspecting the filesystem magic numbers or mount flags?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you using Linux? NFS implementations on Linux support flock. See https://serverfault.com/questions/66919/file-locks-on-an-nfs

Comment: I see hangs with flock with both Linux and Mac clients, with nfs v3 and no lock server running.